# Problem with htaccess rewrite rule for seo friendly url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After a month of trying, I couldn't solve the problem:

I am trying to redirect this url:

```
https://www.example.com/news.php?post=hello-world
```

to this url:

```
https://www.example.com/news/hello-world
```

my code doesn't work and say:

**404 Not Found.**

**The resource requested could not be found on this server!**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /news\.php\?post=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news/%1? [R=302,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an additional internal rewrite rule to silently forward pretty URL to the internal working URL.

Have it like this:

```bash
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /news\.php\?post=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internally rewrite /news/123 to /news.php?post=123
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?post=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```